# How to build ListView from two different Firestore queries?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a single Firestore document called schedule that is a schedule of high school football games.  When a score changes in a game the document is updated.

Each user has their own document in a collection called watched.  This is the games that the user has chosen to watch and has extra fields that they can provide such as their notes about the game.

I have a ListView that displays all of the user's watched games (their watched document).  I need the list view to update when either document updates.

My initial thought is to have one StreamBuilder bound to the schedule document and its child be another StreamBuilder bound to the user's watched document and that one's child be the ListView.

Is this appropriate?  One downside is that if a games in the schedule document gets updated and its not one of the games in the user's watched document, the list will get rebuilt unnecessarily.

Another thought is to have one StreamBuilder bound to the user's watched document and that has a child of ListView.  Then the ListView builder creates another StreamBuilder that is bound to a query against the schedule document to get just that one game.  This means the ListView would contain one StreamBuilder for each item in the watched document.

What is the best way to do this?